# Set SearchView searchSuggestThreshold programmatically

Tags: android, searchview

I am creating a `SearchView` from my `.Java` class not from the `XML` file and I was trying to set the min character length that trigger the search functionality. I found out that I can do this from the `XML` file with the following:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/
 ...
android:searchSuggestThreshold="3"
...
/>
```

But, **I want to know how to do that programmatically**

Comment: afaik you cannot do that